# What is the order of execution of steps in back-propagation algorithm in a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, backpropagation, stochastic-gradient-descent, mini-batch-gradient-descent

I am a machine learning newbie. I am trying to understand the back-propagation algorithm. I have a training dataset of 60 instances/records.

What is the correct order of the process? This one?

- Forward pass of the first instance. Calculate the error.
- Weight update using backpropagation.
- Forward pass of the second instance. Calculate the error.
- Weight update using backpropagation. And so on...

Or

- Forward pass of all instances one by one. Keep track of the error as a vector.
- Weight update using backpropagation.

This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwdjRYUPngE is similar to the second process. Is it correct?

Comment: I think the video you watched is an example of _batch training_. Meaning that you activate an x amount of samples from your set, and you calculate the error over those samples and then change the weights. So you change the weights every x samples. However, if you are a newbie, you should first focus on _online learning_: activating 1 sample, then backpropagating and repeating that for every sample in the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are feasible.

A generalization is to apply the modification of the weights after the presentation of $n$ examples. If $n=1$, this is **online** training. If $n=60$ ($60$, in your case, is the size of the dataset), this is **batch** training. In other cases, this is **mini-batch** training.

The main difference is not the computation complexity of the algorithm, but the theoretical speed of convergence to an "optimal" set of weights.

It is now generally admitted that *online training* is faster. Online training performs a stochastic approximation of the gradient descent method. The true gradient of the cost function over the whole training set is approximated by a gradient at **each** presentation of a training example.

Intuitively, with *batch learning* the weights are modified by an **average** of the gradient over the whole training set and averaging destroys information.

While with stochastic (or mini-batch learning), each example has his word to say. One after the other.

This has also been discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/49528/82135).

Comment: You say "It is now generally admitted that online training is faster", but I am not sure. Faster in terms of convergence? Can you provide a reference (i.e. a reliable paper or book) that supports that claim?